# Why do multidimensional arrays in C++ act differently when passed to a function?

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

In Bjarne Stroustrup's *The C++ Programming Language*, there's an example where a multidimensional array is passed to a function:

```
void print_mij(int m[][], int dim1, int dim2)
{
    for (int i = 0; i!=dim1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j!=dim2; j++) 
            cout << m[i][j] << '\t';
        cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

According to Stroustrup, the expression `m[i][j]` is interpreted as `*(*(m+i)+j)`, which he says isn't what the programmer probably wants. Instead, he says the correct solution is `m[i*dim2+j]`.

What confuses me is that, when multidimensional arrays were first introduced, the former is exactly the syntax used. According to earlier passages, if I declare `m[3][5]` then I can access the first element of the first row and column with `m[0][0]`.

So why is the syntax different between these two examples? It's explained that a multidimensional array is an array of arrays, so it makes sense that the offset of the first dimension is added to the array, then the array there is dereferenced and the second dimension's offset added to that. But the "correct" version he gives acts as though the arrays are allocated in a contiguous format. But that contradicts the syntax given for when an array is first declared.

Comment: Multidimensional array, from your example, is stored, in memory, as an array of `dim2` elements repeated `dim1` times.

Comment: `m[][]` is not legal C++, Stroustrup says that. How `m[i][j]` is interpreted in  a program that doesn't compile is a moot point.

Comment: *the "correct" version he gives acts as though the arrays are allocated in a contiguous format. But that contradicts the syntax given for when an array is first declared.* No it doesn't contradict anything. Arrays are allocated contiguously.

Comment: I am very surprised `void print_mij(int m[][], int dim1, int dim2)` would compile. As @n.m. said, it is not legal. You should get an incomplete type error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The important thing to remember about "multidimensional arrays" in C++, is that they are arrays *of arrays*.

And the important thing to remember about arrays in general is that they decay to a pointer to its first element if passed as an argument to a function.

Now combining these two things, when we pass a "multidimensional array" to a function, it decays to a pointer to an array.

For example, lets say we have the following array:

```
int array[5][10];
```

If we pass this to a function, it will decay to a pointer to `array[0]` (i.e. what is passed is really `&array[0]`), and it will have the type `int (*)[10]`. So the function needs to take that type as argument.

Depending on the situation I recommend using [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead of plain old C-style arrays, or possible [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) for "dynamic" arrays.

Comment: But according to the book, even if you change the type of the argument the method of accessing the elements is wrong. Sorry, I should have made that clear in my question: what's wrong with that method of accessing the elements, using `m[i][j]`? That's the syntax used when the array is first declared outside the function, so why doesn't it work there?

Comment: @RaidenWorley The expected indexing, using e.g. `m[i][j]` works fine when you have e.g. the array `array` declared or defined as shown in my answer. If on the other hand you had e.g. `int array[5 * 10];` then you can use `array[i*10+j]` to *emulate* a "two-dimensional" array.